# IndexPath.Section returns improper index in the heightForRow method of a uitableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsindexpath

i am facing a weird situation . I am working on medical app . I am trying to list the medicines according to the medicine title under sections.

Scenario is i have 18 items for section and each item has say 10 elements.Initially a cell will get called from indexpath.section == 0 to index.section == 17 and then the respective indexpath.rows. But when i am trying to set a dynamic height of the height of the tableviewcell using autolayout ,under the heightForRow method ,instead of indexpath.section == 0 ,what i get is 17 ,ie initially instead of indexpath.section == 0 it is returning 17 .

Comment: you need to keep condition based on section and row in that section not in the table.

Comment: If you have 18 sections then `indexPath.section = 17` is a valid value. What is the actual problem? You should not assume that `heightforRowAtIndexPath` is called for the rows in any specific order.

Comment: @MartinR Scenario is i have 18 items for section and each item has say 10 elements.Initially a cell will get called from indexpath.section == 0 to index.section == 17 and then the respective indexpath.rows. But when i am trying to set a dynamic height of the height of the tableviewcell using autolayout ,under the heightForRow method ,instead of indexpath.section == 0 ,what i get is 17 ,ie initially instead of indexpath.section == 0 it is returning 17